# Android: new String "ISO-8859-1" constructor not defined

Tags: java, android

I have an android app retrieving EditText where content may contain accents (Marché, électrique,...) well in French.

I'm trying to retrieve my text with the following:

```
String nom = new String(vNom.getText().toString(),"ISO-8859-1");
```

but the constructor S`tring(String,String)` is not defined on Android (I'm using this syntax on a server development which is working fine).

how can I retrieve my String in `ISO-8859-1` format in my app ?

Comment: *"I'm using this syntax on a server development which is working fine"* I doubt that. Your first argument there is more likely a byte array, but not a string. And this also works on Android.

Comment: you're right.....sorry about that....here is the right syntaxt  ci.nom = new String(vNom.getText().toString().getBytes(),"ISO-8859-1");

Comment: The constructor doesn't exist because what you're trying to do makes no sense.

Comment: What you are doing makes no sense. Character sets are used when the text interoperates with the OS or external data bytes. All you are doing is transferring one string instance to another - character set is irrelevant

Comment: vNom.getText().toString() is already a String why do you want to convert a String into a String? a String in Java is encoded in UTF-16 which is much better and wider than ISO-8859-1. What do you want to do exactly with this String?

Comment: in fact my String nom is sent to a server with wrong enconding, for instance an EditText set to "bébé" is received by the server like this "BÃƒÂƒÃ‚ÂƒÃƒÂ‚Ã‚Â©bÃƒÂƒÃ‚ÂƒÃƒÂ‚Ã‚Â©" so I assumed it came from a UTF-8 / ISO-8859-1 encoding issue. I didn't know that by default we are using a UTF-16 encoding.

Comment: A `String` when converted to or from `byte[]` causes these errors. A `String` itself has no encoding since it consists of characters, not bytes (Java internally represents it's characters as utf16 but that's basically never relevant) Check the place where you send the string.